# consumir webservice java con Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html5

Es primera vez que estoy haciendo un programa de estas características y necesito un poco de orientación general.

Necesito consumir un webservice (SOA) que esta levantado con JAVA. El Front-End está desarrollado en HTML y pretendía usar jQuery para poder manipular los datos. Mi problema es que no se las configuraciones iniciales para poder hacerlo. Y mi otra pregunta es si debo hacer las funciones con jQuery o se deben hacer en JAVA. También debo llevar un control de tipo de usuarios por lo que sería muy útil si es que me pueden ayudar o quizás entregar algunos links que conozcan para poder ayudarme. Les Agradezco un montón

Comment: ¿El webservice es SOAP o REST? No necesitas jQuery para consumirlo, puedes hacerlo directamente con javascript, pero cómo depende de si es SOAP o REST. Si quieres consumirlo desde un navegador, consumirlo con _java_ no es opción. Si quieres hacerlo desde otro tipo de aplicación, probablemente ni _javascript_ ni _jQuery_ sean la solución, y en cambio, _java_ podría serlo. Creo que debes aclarar esos puntos.

Comment: es Rest amigo.y claro deseo consumirlo desde el navegador. Te agradezco

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [`$.ajax()`](https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/) de `jQuery` para realizar la llamada a tu WebService REST de manera asíncrona.

Debes tener en cuenta que no puedes realizar llamadas ajax a un WebService que se encuentre en otro dominio, debido a la [política del mismo origen](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_del_mismo_origen) que hoy por hoy refuerzan todos los navegadores. Por la misma razón, al ejecutar mi ejemplo, obtendrás un error.

Ajusta la url y los datos de entrada en el ejemplo, sirve esta página desde tu dominio y no debieras tener mayor problema para ejecutarlo.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#get-data').click(function () {
    var showData = $('#show-data');
    showData.text('Ejecutando...');
    var miAPIURL = "https://midominio.com/miServicio/miPuntoDeEntrada";
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: miAPIURL,
      data: {
             campo1: "valor1",
             campo2: "valor2",
             formato: "json"
            },
      async: true,
      dataType: 'json'
      /*
      ,
      complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("completo con status: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function (data) {
        //hacer algo con los datos devueltos
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var miDiv = $('#show-data');
        miDiv.text('Error al ejecutar...');
        console.log("error:" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
      }
      */
    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      console.log("aquí están los datos");
      var miDiv = $('#show-data');
      miDiv.text('¡Exito!');
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      var miDiv = $('#show-data');
      miDiv.text('Error al ejecutar...');
      console.log("ocurrió un error");
    })
    .always(function (){
      console.log("la llamada terminó");
    })
    ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Request JSON Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" id="get-data">Ejecutar WebService (Rest)</a>
    <div id="show-data"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```